# How does SFDX and org changes work for Admins?

Tags: salesforcedx, sandbox, scratch-org, admin, continuous-integration

I've been trying to put together a plan for using SFDX in conjunction with a CI tool like Azure DevOps.  It appears to have all of the right pieces for deploying metadata to/from git and scratch orgs/sandboxes.

How does a team track changes that an admin (clicks not code) makes?  Is there a limited recommended scope of what SFDX is supposed to track?

Comment: You could probably setup something with into CI command chain to use `sfdx force:source:retrieve` on different metadata that admins would adjust

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally, admins' clicks-not-code should also result as metadata in a repo somewhere. Flows, processes, page layouts, etc can all be sourced to a repo and then distributed through CI, thus enhancing the experience. It would be even more ideal if your admin could simply create a scratch org, deploy your existing metadata, make any clicks-not-code changes, then pull those changes back to the repo (this is actually the intended pattern to use).

There are, of course, situations that this won't work for (not *all* metadata can be deployed via API), but for the majority of use cases, your admins should follow the same steps as a developer in terms of making repo changes.

In fact, with Unlocked Packages, it goes one step further; any rogue changes made by an administrator can be overwritten by packages, thus ensuring a consistent state of metadata. This sounds annoying, but it's actually incredibly liberating knowing that you can replicate your org in mere minutes with close to 100% accuracy.

Comment: You are like the Jon Skeet of Salesforce

Comment: @KyleJV Thanks for the compliment!